# how to read content from text file selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a get request through which I get a txt file

```
driver.get(url = main_url+f'/bot/{bot_id}/users')
```

Can I read content from a file without downloading that file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for web scraping. Here is a useful [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-web-scraping-tutorial/) about how you can do web scraping using the Requests module and BeautifulSoup.

I am also very new to this and hence you may be able to find much better tools to achieve your outcome, but this surely would be a nice start.